# Open XQuery panel in BaseX

Tags: basex

I have tried many times to open the **XQuery panel** on **BaseX**. I've searched just about anything on the GUI opened any panel that could be opened and searched throughout the documentation of BaseX, no go.

[image]

**EDIT**

When I go to `View > Editor` **I do not get the XQuery panel** I get this one:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query editor is hidden under "View" -> "Editor", or using the hotkey <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> (on OS X, using <kbd>Cmd</kbd> instead).

[image]

Edit: In the updated screenshot, the query editor is already visible. The "XQuery" view was renamed some time ago, when the editor was enhanced. Just press the "+" button in the tab view to open a new tab to write XQuery code.

[image]

Comment: Now I see – actually you already found it. :) The first screenshot you used is outdated. Where did you find that?

Comment: Here it is: http://basex.org/uploads/pics/BaseX_ExploreYourData.png it has a neat window where you can put XQuery language inside instead of the terrible one line where you must squeze your statements in my case.

Comment: It is also the first image you see when you enter in the company's GUI explanation guide: http://basex.org/products/gui/

Comment: You can use exactly this editor pane. It was just renamed. I added another screenshot, and will take action that the old screenshot will get replaced (I'm somewhat affiliated with the BaseX team). Thank you for reporting that.

Comment: Thank you for you amazing assistance and sorry for the "adjectives" on the UI i used.